# How to slice a string value that will be displayed in a HTML tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do I slice a string passed from Django context that will be displayed in a HTML tag?

Comment: This is not the right way to ask a question on SO, kindly go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a number of very powerful template tags that you can use from withing the template. There is one specifically for slicing a string. Details are here;

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Example usage in the template.

`{{ 'Here is a string'|slice:"2" }}`

The result would display 'He'.